# Define a date that is 1 month ago from current date

Tags: timestamp, jmeter

I want to define a variable **that will give me the current date minus 30 days** (meaning 1 month ago).

For now, I only have this variable that gives me the current date:

```
${__time(yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssX)}
```

Answer (score 5):

Check out following JMeter functions:

- [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) - returns time in milliseconds since 1st of Jan 1970 if used without parameters
- [__longSum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__longSum) - add or subtract 2 or more [Long](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) values
- [__javaScript()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) - execute arbitrary JavaScript code

Putting all together:

```
${__javaScript(new Date(${__longSum(${__time(,)},-2592000000,)}),)}
```

where:

- `2592000000` == 30 (days) x 24 (hours in day) * 60 (minutes in hour) * 60 (seconds in minute) * 1000 (milliseconds in second)
- new Date(current time - 30 days) - converts Unix timestamp into [JavaScript Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Demo:

[image: Functions - 30 days]

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series for comprehensive information on above and other JMeter functions.